# Set value in field depending on condition

Tags: android, automation

We have a collection data scanner which has application (actually, 1C) poorly adopted for our needs. We use it only because it can utilize laser beam capabilities.

I configured it to show number of scan times written in one field, and number of additional scans written below when laser points onto barcode. I need whenever scan times is 0, set additional scans to 1, otherwise 0. Is there any application which can do this automatically?

May be there are other (better) applications, I publish requirements for that case:

- work on android 4.x
- it should scan barcodes using laser beam, not by camera;
- it should have ability to define custom fields;
- it should have ability to import and export data;
- it should detect if barcode is scanned again;
- (optionally) it should show and save scan result whenever laser beam is activated, without any necessity to launch special program

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Izzy thanks I think this question would fit Software Recommendations, so can somebody move it there?

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: I feel that this is specific to whatever app you are using to store and display the data. What is it?

Comment: @Mawg, it is mobile version of infamous russian program for accounting, 1C Mobile Trading.